# Isomorphism and multiplication table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

According to this image:

[image]

I would like to know why isomorphism implies that if $AB=C$ then $A'B'=C'$

To do this, I have to prove that the isomorphism, call it f, has to satisfy: $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$, but how do I prove this?

Comment: IMO, that "in other words" is misleading: what follows is not the same as stated till that point (bijectivity), but just an additional, key feature of "isomorphism" *definition*, namely *operation preservation*.

Comment: I have looked for group isomorphism in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147632/isomorphisms-preserve-structure-operation-or-order

But how do I prove that an isomorphism satisfies these conditions? Is it just defined like that?

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism is *defined* like that. You can define that two groups are *isomorphic* based on a *diffrent* definition, and come up to the *lemma* that two groups are isomorphic iff there is an operation-preserving bijection between them. But this is another story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the definition of a group isomorphism in the quoted text is incorrect. The standard definition is as follows:

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups.

- A function $\varphi: G \to H$ is a **group homomorphism** if for all $x , y \in G$, $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y)$.
- A function $\varphi : G \to H$ is a **group isomorphism** if it is a group homomorphism and a bijection (equivalently  $\varphi$ is a bijection and there exists a group homomorphism $\psi : H \to G$ such that $\varphi \circ \psi = \operatorname{id}_H$ and $\psi \circ \varphi = \operatorname{id}_G$).

Therefore the desired $\varphi(gh) = \varphi(g)\varphi(h)$ is simply part of the definition.